# can a nation encompassing a diaspora with no geographical delineation also be or have its own state

Tags: statehood

Nation is often considered a synonym for state. But a nation may exist with no border. The Welsh are a nation. Can a nation with no geographical connection be or own a state?

Comment: I think this basically ends up coming down to semi-arbitrary definitions. Whats really important here is does the rest of the word acknowledge your theoretical nation as a state.

Comment: This becomes a language/semantics debate. Probably better asked on English.se or the like.

Comment: [The advent of the Internet provided the means for people to create many new micronations, whose members are scattered all over the world and interact mostly by electronic means, often calling their nations "nomadic countries". The differences between such Internet micronations, other kinds of social networking groups, and role playing games are often difficult to define.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micronation)

Comment: Wales isn't an example of an entity without a reasonably well accepted political border either. The Basque country or (the Island of) Ireland might fit your purposes as an example better.

Comment: The Jews were in exile for almost 2000 years and they were a nation for that entire time. The *Palestinians* did not exist at all as a nation until the Yasir Arafat and his terrorist group invented them. These are the two extremes showing that a *nation* can exist without actual territory.

Comment: Most definitions of *state* require a defined territory.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(polity).

Comment: @sabbahillel - I’d edit that comment if I were you....

Comment: @Obie2.0 The statements in that comment are accurate. I counted the Jewish exile as from the destruction of the Second Temple in 70 C.E. until the setting up of the state of Israel in 1948 C.E.

Comment: @sabbahillel - I mean, they might be literally accurate (depending on definitions), but they sure seem just a *tad* biased.

Comment: @Obie2.0 The term *Palestine* actually comes from *Philistine* (as used in the Bible) which originally meant *invaders* in the language of the time (of Abraham and earlier). When the Romans destroyed the Jewish state, they used the term *Palestine* in order to hide the fact that they had taken over Judea and exiled the Jews. This continued until the British Mandate took over after World War I. The term *Palestinian* was actually used by the British to refer to the Jewish inhabitants of the *Palestine Mandate*. After the Israeli declaration of independence in 1948 C.E., the term was dropped.

Comment: @sabbahillel - I'm sorry you feel that way. There's no pretending; there actually are Palestinians, just as there are Israelis. Regardless of how either nation came about (and there are plenty of people to claim that the foundation of either was illegitimate). You sound like a Bibi fan to me.... :)

Comment: @Obie2.0 Ahmed Shukeiry founded the *Palestine Liberation Organization* as a terrorist group in 1964 to destroy the State of Israel and pretended that the Arab immigrants into the region were the *Palestinians*. Up until that time, no Arabs used the term to refer to refer to themselves. Yasir Arafat took over as Chairman using his Fatah faction in 1969. My mistake in the original comment was using the name of Arafat instead of Ahmed Shukeiry.

Comment: @sabbahillel - Who cares? You seem stuck in the past - still mad at the Romans for coming up with the "wrong" name, for example. Maybe you dislike "Israel," too, and want it changed back to Judea? Here in the real world, Israel and Palestine (and their respective residents) both are very real, and whinging about 50-year-old (or 80-year-old, or 2000-year-old) events won't change that.

Comment: @Obie2.0 No I am just explaining the actual genesis of the term, that is all.

Comment: @sabbahillel - ...which you believe to be a matter of scholarly interest, totally unrelated to the current political situation...right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74245/discussion-between-sabbahillel-and-obie-2-0).

Answer (score 2):

The answer largely depends on what you consider "State" and is basically definition dependent.

Wikipedia openly indicates that there's no clear definition:

> There is no academic consensus on the most appropriate definition of the state.[5] The term "state" refers to a set of different, but interrelated and often overlapping, theories about a certain range of political phenomena.[6] The act of defining the term can be seen as part of an ideological conflict, because different definitions lead to different theories of state function, and as a result validate different political strategies.[7] According to Jeffrey and Painter, "if we define the 'essence' of the state in one place or era, we are liable to find that in another time or space something which is also understood to be a state has different 'essential' characteristics" [8]

1. Some definitions don't impose a territorial/geographical aspect:

   > 3. (also State) a an organized political community under one government; a commonwealth; a nation. (*Wikipedia citing Thompson, Della, ed. (1995). "state". Concise Oxford English Dictionary (9th ed.). Oxford University Press*)
2. Yet, there are also definitions that impose a territorial requirement, including most common ones:

   Under such definitions, "no territory" means "no state":

   > Speakers of American English often use the terms state and government as synonyms,[note 1] with both words referring to an organized political group **that exercises authority over a particular territory**. (*Wikipedia*).
   >
   > The most commonly used definition is Max Weber's,[9][10][11][12][13] which describes the state as a compulsory political organization with a centralized government that maintains a monopoly of the legitimate use of force within a certain territory
   >
   > Another commonly accepted definition of the state is the one given at the **Montevideo Convention on Rights and Duties of States in 1933. It defined state** as a space that possess the following : A permanent population, **a defined territory** and a government that is capable of maintaining **effective control over the corresponding territory** and of conducting International relations with other states.

---

Examples of nations that are states without firm geographic delineations:

- Many Native American tribes, while constituting nations, were rather geographically disbursed due to their culture (migratory hunting, e.g. on the Great Planes).

  As an example, Lacota and other Sioux for example were all over the place, before displacing other tribes in the area of Black Hills (and even then were pretty geographically dispersed).

  At that, Sioux Confederation can likely be considered a state - they had a government and soveregnity (to the point of US government conducting treaties with them).
- One may quibble that ISIS (Islamic State of Iraq and Syria) qualifies. They are somewhat diffused, despite holding specific territory, yet are a state for now.

---

Of separate note, there's newer political theories that postulate less-territorial states, given humankind's development trajectory, in near future. They are partly based on the following factors:

- Portable productivity. In the older days, you had to have a field to plow, and building to place your blacksmithy and a house to live in.

  Ironically, that's precisely what allowed pre-agricultural Sioux to be a state without a defined territory - they were portable.

  On the other extreme are people who can make a living while traveling - typically, various IP-producing types (journalists, creative types, programmers etc...) - and the more we move towards IP-based economy and post-scarcity society, the more this becomes feasible. Advent of 3d-printing improves the picture even more.
- Increased ability for asymmetric warfare.

  One factor that made territorial holdings important to a state is that holding territory allows one to amass the force needed to protect one's sovereignty, as far as economy, logistics, manpower and tactics.

  Project into the future; where man-portable nuclear devices are possible as the *least* of dangers; and nano-warfare and cyber-warfare is possible; and don't require either territory or large autonomy.

  As such, a territory-less nation that has access to such threats can protect their sovereignty against other nations.
- Easier travel, largely tied to cheaper energy and better transportation.

  Again, this benefits both types of extremes - pre-agricultural hunter/gatherer nomads, who need a horse (or two feet), a tent/backpack, and enough fodder. As well as more futuristic member of a nation who can buy a world-circumnavigating boat; or travel by land freely on any continent end to end reasonably cheaply and easily.